# Comparing dynamic html element ids with SQL Table cloumn and insert matching column values

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, xml, xslt

What I have is my HTML is rendered dynamically from XML/XSL and they have a new different number of fields and so different ids.

what I have is set of questions generated and each time number of questions are different and here I get ids of all questions whether radio, checkbox, TextField, dropdown, picklist.

Now what I will be doing is pick id's of all Questions and compare with database question id's that are already present in database table column and put answers in appropriate answer column. answer against the relevent question.

pardon for my poor English but any idea how that can be done would be much appreciated.

kind Regards

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: Although your task sounds feasible using XSLT we definitely need some input data and some desired output data to give you any concrete hints. Could you add those to your question? Thanks!